# (Linux) How can i grep this? (XML format)

Tags: grep

```
<host city="Santa Rosa" country="USA" hostnames="50-0-143-139.dsl.static.sonic.net" ip="50.0.143.139" latitude="38.3928" longitude="-122.7507" port="80" updated="30.01.2015"><data>HTTP/1.0 200 OK
    Date: Fri, 30 Jan 2015 00:15:54 GMT
    Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
    X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.9
    Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=5vbu0vva1rvdaqvkk12kk2gjc4; path=/
    Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
    Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
    Pragma: no-cache
    Set-Cookie: _pmxi_session=%7C%7C%7C%7C; path=/
    X-Pingback: http://www.rasputinmusic.com/xmlrpc.php
    Link: &lt;http://wp.me/18fQM&gt;; rel=shortlink
    Vary: Accept-Encoding
    Transfer-Encoding: chunked
    Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Basically all I want is the value inside X-Pingback, in this case "http://www.rasputinmusic.com/xmlrpc.php"

How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think `grep` is the best way; I recommend using `awk`. If your data is in `text.xml`, try:

> `awk '/X-Pingback: /{print $NF}' text.xml`

This searches for lines that begin with "`X-Pingback:` " and then prints the last field of those lines. The results may be redirected to a file using the redirection metacharacter `>`. For example:

> `awk '/X-Pingback: /{print $NF}' text.xml > filtered.txt`

Comment: to output file though?